# Change number after dollar sign to 0 in string

Tags: ruby

What I am trying to do is to change number that comes after $ sign into 0 in a string. I could do simple "find $ sign then change next thing after it into 0", but the problem is that number may have different number of digits. Another problem is that number might be non-integer like "2.5" so it has to tolerate comma, or negative numbers like "-2"
For example:

I have an equation which is string type: `x^(-2) + 4x + 123 + 42.2 + 1`

I write it as follows: `x^($-2) + $4x + $123 + $42.2 + 1`

Output that I am trying to get should be: `x^(0) + 0x + 0 + 1`

Do you have an idea how to do that?

For now I have came up with idea, but I don't know if such method exist in ruby.

```
x=0
while index('$',x+1) do
   x = index('$',x+1)
   #function that does translating
end
```

In the loop, there could be a function that trims every digit until it find non-numeric character (with exception of starting - and . imitating negative or floating point number) and then puts in that place "0".

Comment: Something like this? `"x^($-2) + $4x + $123 + 42.2 + 1".gsub(/\$-?\d+(\.\d+)?/,'0')
#=> "x^(0) + 0x + 0 + 42.2 + 1"`

Comment: It treats all occurrences that match the pattern defined in the first parameter of gsub, namely numbers with a `$` in front. I guess just try what I suggested on your examples and see if it's what you require.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Post it as answer so I can mark it as solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's the mathematical goal of this transformation? I don't get it.

Comment: It's not for mathematical purposes. Let's say its quiz where user has to put pre-transformation number in places of zeros. While creating said quiz, creator can decide which numbers user has to guess by using $.

Comment: Why are `123` and `1` treated differently? I suggest that in future you hold off selecting an answer for awhile (> two hours, perhaps). Quick-draw selections can discourage other answers and short-circuit readers who are still working on their answers. There's no rush.

Comment: Uhm, sorry but I think you're the one who made just a quick glance and then commented. It's intentional that 1 was left as it was, since it did not have $ in front of it. I tested @sagarypandya82 answer and for now it does everything that I need (and what was stated in this post).

Comment: Please not that both @sagarpandya82's answer and my answer return a string (the same string) that differs from the string you say you want. Please explain. More generally you should have stated the substitution rules you want to apply.  The reference to `x^(-2) + 4x + 123 + 42.2 + 1` appears to be irrelevant, so I don't know why it's mentioned. The starting point would appear to be `x^($-2) + $4x + $123 + $42.2 + 1`.

Comment: I don't understand what's your point. Produced string by @sagarpandya82's is exactly as the output that I wanted. Since he provided answer faster, I have marked it as valid one. Not to mention that his code is more mistake-proof. Try for example `"x^($-2) + $4x + $-123- $42.2 + 1"` and see the difference for yourself.

Comment: You said you wanted `x^(0) + 0x + 0 + 1`. @sagarpandya82 and I obtained `#=> "x^(0) + 0x + 0 + 0 + 1"` (an extra `+ 0`). I was not complaining about your choice of answer to checkmark. What should `"x^($-2) + $4x + $-123- $42.2 + 1"` return? I'll edit my answer after you tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regex with `String#gsub` like follows:

```
"x^($-2) + $4,000x + $123 + $42.2 + 1".gsub(/\$-?\d+(\,\d+)*(\.\d+)?/,'0')
#=> "x^(0) + 0x + 0 + 0 + 1"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
r = /
    \$        # match '$'
    (?:       # begin a non-capture group
      -(?>\d) # match a hyphen followed by a digit in a positive lookahead
      |       # or
      [\d,.]+ # match one of the characters one or more times
    )         # end the non-capture group
    /x        # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

which is conventionally written as follows.

```
r = /\$(?:-(?>\d)|[\d,.]+)/

"x^($-2) + $4,000x + $123 + $42.2 + 1".gsub(r, '0')
  #=> "x^(0) + 0x + 0 + 0 + 1"
"x^($-2) + $4x + $-123- $42.2 + 1".gsub(r, '0')
  #=> "x^(0) + 0x + 023- 0 + 1"
```

Comment: Only "-" before a number should be removed. For example `x^($-2) + $4x + $-123- $42.2 + 1".gsub(/\$[-\d,.]+/, '0') => "x^(0) + 0x + 0 0 + 1" ` for your regex while it should be `=> "x^(0) + 0x + 0 + 42.2 + 1 - 0- 23"`. I still apprieciate your answer.

Comment: I modified my answer to remove  `"-"` when followed by a digit, but I don't get a return value that is even close to what you say it should be. For example, why is `$42.2` converted to `0` in your first example but to `42.2` in your second answer? And why is `$-123-` converted to `23` (i.e, both hyphens are removed) and then moved to the end of the string? These are rhetorical questions; I'm not really interested in the answers, as I've gone as far as I can answering such a poorly-specified question. Note @sagarpandya82's regex returns `=> "x^(0) + 0x + 0- 0 + 1"` for your second example.